# Baby Talk on warning toddlers against touching, say, objects too hot to touch

Tags: phrase-request

I am curious about baby talk people use to warn toddlers not to touch dangerous things such as objects too hot to touch.

Think of a coffee cup, too hot for them to touch, what would you say? Would you say, for example: Noooo?

Looking for set phrases, *sounds*, and words or anything used in this situation.

Comment: So what is your question? Did you hide it somewhere? :-)

Comment: Thought was clear! Check it out now.

Comment: Better! So you had hidden your question!;) But this is a really fun question. I love to know the answer. In my language we say jzza /ʤzʌ/:-)

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a standard orthography for it, but ***Ah-Ah!*** is a standard "warning" (primarily reserved for adults addressing children, or contemptuous mimicking of that context), that invariably means one or more of *Don't do that! Don't touch! Stop!*

Comment: Or, you could talk to the kid like a normal person rather than treating them like they can't understand real speech.... What's wrong with saying "Don't touch! That's too hot and you'll burn yourself!"

Comment: @Catija But toddlers would not know what burning means, would they?

Comment: Or you could use baby-talk to talk to an adult. To every thing there is a season. :) Seriously, please don't vote to close this question. It's the kind of thing that dictionaries don't cover but native speakers all know through personal experience. IOW, it's perfect for ELL.

Comment: @Sina They'll never learn if you don't teach them. Toddlerhood and childhood are about learning things. If you dumb stuff down for them, they'll never learn anything.

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail.  am retracting my close vote.

Comment: @Catija I know what you mean, but parents never like their beloved toddler experience burnning. So they just inhearently use some sounds like that **jzza** in my language to buy themselves time while distracting their baby's notice form let's say heater, to jump and save him/her!

Comment: I would not leave hot coffee anywhere that they could potentially touch it, or if they got too close I would pick it up (the coffee, not the toddler). I suppose I could add a "No, no, no, no....(too hot...not for you)" with an emphasis on "NO". I believe most kids learn the word "no" before they learn "yes."

Comment: @Sina: there is man on American television who uses a similar sibilant sound to train dogs.

Comment: @Sina: it is not intended as an insult. Such sounds seem to have a power to grab the attention at a deep animal level. Compare the sound we make to get someone's attention surreptitiously: Pssst!

Comment: @TRomano There is a difference. I told perents use sounds to distract their toddler from going toward danger, like a hot iron, and they do not train them using such a sound. Then of course they speak to their children to teach them that they should not touch a hot thing and... .

Answer (score 3):

In our family (3 kids) we used the word **No** from a very early age, as soon as baby starts trying to do things that are dangerous or otherwise problematic. Then add a suitable modifier:

> No, Hot
>
> No, Sharp
>
> No, Hurt

As a general policy we don't use baby-talk in the sense of using baby-ish speach

> Goo, goo, diddums

etc. We do keep the sentence structure very simple as in the examples above, but then usually follow up with a more complete sentence.

> No, Hot. Dad's tea is very hot, it will burn you.

Thek kids as they learned to speak started to use words such as **Hot** themselves.